# Why there's no TTL field in an ethernet frame?

Tags: ethernet, ttl

As far as I experienced, there's nothing like a TTL field in an ethernet frame. An IP datagram for instance provides a TTL field to prevent packages from being passed around for a perpetual period of time. Of course ethernet provides a mechanism to prohibit perpetual sending: Ethernet just calls the spanning tree algorithm to destroy any circles that may lead to perpetual sending. But thats a lot of work in comparison to a simple TTL field that provides the same (or similar).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about network packet design (try http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

When ethernet was first invented, it started out as a simple communication solution without any smarthub or sophisticated router on the media.  Just dumping frames to the cable, backing off and retrying when collision occurred.  Keeping it simple and no modification to the packets.

In a way, no TTL is somewhat inherited from the original design.  And to stay backward compatible.